# Send email for a multiple addresses

Tags: linux, python

How can I send email for multiple addresses in my Python code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import sys, getopt

recipient=''
subject=''
body=''

try:
    myopts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"r:s:m:")
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print (str(e))
    print("Usage: %s -r recipient -s subject -m message" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(2)

for o, a in myopts:
    if o == '-r':
        recipient=a
    elif o == '-s':
        subject=a
    elif o == '-m':
        body=a

server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 587
sender = 'foo@bar'
password = 'password'
headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject,
           "To: " + recipient,
           "MIME-Version: 1.0",
           "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
session.login(sender, password)
session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
session.quit()
```

Comment: This is not the site to ask programming questions. You have an account on [so] so you should use that for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a list of strings where each string corresponds to one recipient, like this:

```
recipients = ['aaa@example.com', 'bbb@example.com']
session.sendmail(sender, recipients, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
```

Comment: One bash script call this python script by command line so
i can't prepare a list with this method because the e-mail addresses don't are fixed them came from whois query.

Comment: In need send email like that '# script.py -r email0@x, email1@x,...'

Comment: For that, the problem is reduced to "how to extract multiple arguments in python". Like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109436/processing-multiple-values-for-one-single-option-using-getopt-optparse)